# getRuntime().exec(<command>): <command> not working

Tags: java, runtime.exec, xinput

I have getRuntime().exec() calls in my program; however, two of them will not work:

```
public static final ROTCW = "xrandr -o left"
public static final CALCW1 = "xinput --set-prop 11 \"Evdev Axis Inversion\" 0 1"
public static final CALCW2 = "xinput --set-prop 11 \"Evdev Axes Swap\" 1";

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{       
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(ROTCW);
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(CALCW1);
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(CALCW2);}
    catch (IOException ioe){ ioe.printStackTrace();}
}});
```

ROTCW definitely works (the screen rotates cw), but it does not calibrate (CALCW). Typing the CALCWs manually in the same terminal tab as the one I started the program with does *not* work, but typing it into a new terminal tab/window *does* work.

Why does this happen, and what fixes it?

Comment: Try running it WITHOUT a shell, as you do with exec. ;)

Comment: Uhm, I suspect you have `... Sring ROTCW ...` in your actual code.

Comment: Edited: it looks like && is what's breaking it.

Comment: After debugging, I'm left with CALCW1 and CALCW2 just not doing anything. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement the `&&` logic directly in Java:

```
public static final String
    ROTCW = "xrandr -o left",
    CALCW1[] = {"xinput", "--set-prop", "11", "\"Evdev Axis Inversion\"", "0", "1"},
    CALCW2[] = {"xinput", "--set-prop", "11", "\"Evdev Axes Swap\"", "1"};

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{       
    try {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(ROTCW).waitFor();
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(CALCW1);
        p.waitFor();
        if( p.exitValue() != 0 ) Runtime.getRuntime().exec(CALCW2);
    }
    catch (IOException ioe){ ioe.printStackTrace();}
}});
```

Comment: waitFor() did not help, nor did simply calling .exec() separately for ROTCW, CALCW1, and CALCW2. Thanks though.

Comment: Now that I think about it, it makes sense to put another `waitFor()` on the `ROTCW` process (see edit) have you tried that?

Comment: To clarify: the `waitFor()` on the `CALCW1` process is to make sure it finishes before getting the exit value and deciding whether to call `CALCW2`.

Comment: I've played with waitFor()s, but nothing is hanging up; rather, CALCW1&2 are not doing anything. Something may be wrong with how it's executed via bash.

Comment: One more idea (see edit), basically switch to the array version of `exec`, maybe the spaces in the 3rd argument are breaking something.

Comment: Nope, no change. Thanks for all the ideas though, upvoted your comments :)

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a shell with

```
 public static final CALCW = "bash -c 'xinput --set-prop 11 \"Evdev Axis Inversion\" 0 1" +
     " && xinput --set-prop 11 \"Evdev Axes Swap\" 1'"
```

To clarify `&&` is a syntax for a shell and just another argument for a program.

Comment: you should clarify that "&&" is shell syntax and that is why you need to run with "bash".

Comment: This did not work for me, tried both in the program and manually. Same results as mine above.

Comment: Can you try retrieving the output and errors?  Its likely to be outputting an error which you are discarding.

Comment: There's no java-side error, though. How can I capture a command line error via java?

Comment: Runtime.exec() returns a Process from which you can getErrorStream() and getOutputStream(). You can also waitFor() the process to finish. BTW: Can the two programs run at a the same time?

Comment: waitFor() does not yield any developments (see trutheality below), and the output/error streams don't return anything. :/ Thanks for all the suggestions though.

Answer (score 0):

It's old question but I didn't find the answer, so I'm publishing one.

You have to use array version of exec() and without quotation marks in properly section of the command:

```
CALCW1[] = {"xinput", "set-prop", "11", "Evdev Axis Inversion", "0", "1"}
```